# Remove or hide style on element

Tags: jquery

I want to remove the last right border in a row of links?

```
#mainMenu a {
display: block;
float: left;
height: 20px;
padding: 0px 10px 2px 10px;
border-right: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: arial, verdana, 'sans-serif';
color: #CFCFCF;
}
```

I have tested to change the color of the border to the same color as the background, but it's not working and I'm looking for some help. Perhaps there is a better way?

```
$("a#mainMenu:last").css({border-right: '1px solid #ffffff'});
```

Comment: Selector will only find a single element with `id=mainMenu` and there can only be one since ID's must be unique.  Need to show html

Comment: disregard html...CSS and selector are reverse from each other

Comment: [`{'border-right':'1px solid #ffffff'} is just an object.`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11194940/144665)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS and selector shown are reverse from each other, this should be correct to find last A assuming a single level menu

```
  $("#mainMenu a:last").css("border-right", "none")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pure css:

```
#mainMenu a:last-of-type { border-right: none; }
```

If you do it with jQuery, be sure to run the code inside a `$(document).ready()` function block and change `border-right` to `borderRight`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mainMenu a:last").css({borderRight: 'none'});
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jackwanders/9pCuz/1/)